# How to trigger karate gatling distributed test?

Tags: karate

We want to run karate gatling distributed mode to test API performance.

Here is the performance test class for master node

```
public class TestPerformanceDocker {
    @Test
    void test(){
        //master node server ip
        String serverUrl= "127.0.0.1";
        String threads = System.getProperty("THREADS");
        String rampDuration = System.getProperty("RAMP_DURATION");
        String constantDuration =System.getProperty("CONST_DURATION");
        //slave node amounts
        Integer executorCount=Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("NODES_COUNT"));
        String cmd ="mvn gatling:test -DTHREADS="+threads+" -DRAMP_DURATION="+rampDuration+" -DCONST_DURATION="+constantDuration+"";
        GatlingMavenJobConfig config = new GatlingMavenJobConfig(executorCount, serverUrl, 9090) {};
        config.setMainCommand(cmd);
        JobManager<Integer> manager = new JobManager(config);
        manager.start();
        manager.waitForCompletion();
    }
}
```

Start the master node with cmd :
docker container run -d -t --network=karate_network --name karate_boss --privileged karate mvn clean test -Dtest=TestPerformanceDocker -DTHREADS=3 -DRAMP_DURATION=600 -DCONST_DURATION=600

Face with error log below:

2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.259 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.http.HttpServer - server started: f224cb587867:9090
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.261 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.job.JobManager - added to queue: 1
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.262 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.job.JobManager - added to queue: 2
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.265 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.job.JobManager - added to queue: 3
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.283 [1671544535281] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - command: [docker, run, --rm, --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN, -e, KARATE_JOBURL=http://127.0.0.1:9090, ptrthomas/karate-chrome], working dir: null
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.285 [1671544535281] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - command: [docker, run, --rm, --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN, -e, KARATE_JOBURL=http://127.0.0.1:9090, ptrthomas/karate-chrome], working dir: null
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.285 [1671544535281] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - command: [docker, run, --rm, --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN, -e, KARATE_JOBURL=http://127.0.0.1:9090, ptrthomas/karate-chrome], working dir: null
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.348 [1671544535281-out] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.349 [1671544535281-out] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - See 'docker run --help'.
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.357 [1671544535281] WARN  com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - exit code was non-zero: 125 - [docker, run, --rm, --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN, -e, KARATE_JOBURL=http://127.0.0.1:9090, ptrthomas/karate-chrome] working dir: null
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.363 [1671544535281-out] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.364 [1671544535281-out] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - See 'docker run --help'.
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.365 [1671544535281-out] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.366 [1671544535281-out] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - See 'docker run --help'.
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.369 [1671544535281] WARN  com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - exit code was non-zero: 125 - [docker, run, --rm, --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN, -e, KARATE_JOBURL=http://127.0.0.1:9090, ptrthomas/karate-chrome] working dir: null
2022-12-20 21:55:35 13:55:35.371 [1671544535281] WARN  com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - exit code was non-zero: 125 - [docker, run, --rm, --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN, -e, KARATE_JOBURL=http://127.0.0.1:9090, ptrthomas/karate-chrome] working dir: null

With the reference article in official github, we want to run the karate-gatling with distributed mode for API testing.

Reference assets:

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Distributed-Testing#jenkins-config

Comment: to be very honest, not many teams seem to be using the distributed option and there can be issues. my recommendation is please proceed only if you are confident of being able to contribute code and fixes. that said, some teams are using this